# Does C++17 provide a cross-platform scheme to record compiler version and options like Fortran?

Tags: c++, compilation, c++17

## Question

Modern Fortran offers a few cross-platform mechanisms to record the compiler version and settings used to build an application. What methods does C++17 have to capture this information? The book by Horton and Van Weert, [Beginning C++17](https://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484233658), does not appear to address this question.

The Fortran tools are surveyed below.

### 1. Access to compiler versions and options

The `iso_fortran_env` in Fortran provides a standard way to access the compiler version and settings used to compile a code. A sample snippet follows.

#### Code sample

```
program check_compiler

use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : compiler_options, compiler_version

implicit none

    write ( *, 100 ) "compiler version = ", compiler_version ()
    write ( *, 100 ) "compiler options = ", trim ( compiler_options () )

 100  format ( A, A, / )
      stop "normal termination . . ."

end program check_compiler
```

#### Sample output

```
$ gfortran -o check_compiler check_compiler.f08 
$ ./check_compiler
compiler version = GCC version 8.0.0 20170604 (experimental)

compiler options = -fPIC -mmacosx-version-min=10.12.7 -mtune=core2

STOP normal termination . . .
```

### 2. Probing and interacting with host OS

Fortran commands like `execute_command_line`, `get_command`, and `get_environment_variable` offer another route to record information at compile time.

Comment: 1) No, it doesn't provide such a thing. 2) Don't really understand what you are asking - you can use functions like std::getenv() to query environment variables.

Comment: I've constructed Makefile that would output the options as text into a header file like `#define CXX_OPTIONS "blah blah blah"` that I could then output if the user typed `coolapp --help`.  Which was more for myself and the other devs on the team, but it was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching the [C++20 standard draft, which is available in GitHub](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/), I find [no results](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/search?q=compiler%20version&unscoped_q=compiler%20version) for closely-localted "compiler" and "version", nor have I found something like this looking at the text of the standard.

C++20 is at this time still very close to C++17, and certainly such a mechanism has not been removed, so I think it's pretty safe to say that there's no such thing in C++20.

Answer (score 7):

> What methods does C++17 have to capture this information?

None. The C++ standard does not even recognize the concept of "compiler" or "options"; there is merely the "implementation".

Furthermore, it would not really make sense, as different C++ files linked into the same program can be compiled with different options. And I'm not just talking about DLL/SOs; you can in theory statically link files that were compiled with different options or even different compiler versions.

Different compilers have ways to specify what version they are through macros. But each one has its own way to report this.

Comment: These caveats generally apply also to the Fortran aspects.  So perhaps there could be closer matching between Fortran and C++?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Point well taken. When using tools like Spack which builds the entire dependency tree, we have some control over the compilation environment. The command `cat proc/version` reveals the system compiler. It would be nice to query the Spack builds and confirm the compiler version and settings. We can accomplish this in our  `Fortran` files. The hope was that `C++` offered a similar tool.

Answer (score -1):

Each compiler injects their own preproxessor tokens indicating itmwas compiled by them, and what version.  These tokens are cross platform on compilers that compile on and to kore than one platdorm, such as icc, gcx and clang.

There are now standard defined ways to detect the existence of some srd header files.  Boost has extensive headers that decode compiler capabilities based of a myriad of techniques.

`__cplusplus` in theory is defined to the standard version, but compilers lie.

Answer (score -1):

The language standard specifies macros `__cplusplus` that encode the version of the standard that the compiler claims to support.  It expands to `201703L` on a C++17 compiler, `201710L` on a C++14 compiler, and so on.  It might also define `_STDC` and `_STDC_VERSION`. Beyond that, everything is a vendor-specific extension that you should look up in your compiler's manual.

Some but not all compilers, including GCC and Clang, predefine a macro named `__VERSION__` that expands to a string describing the compiler version.  You can check for this with `#ifdef`.  Beyond that, many compilers contain macros that expand to version numbers, which you can stringify and concatenate.  However, be aware that some compilers treat these as compatibility tests, and will claim to be a different compiler if you ask. In addition to its own version numbers, Clang defines `__GNUC__`, `__GNUC_VERSION__` and `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__` to indicate its compatibility with GCC, and the Windows version will also define `_MSC_VER`, `_MSC_FULL_VER` and so on in its Microsoft-compatiblity mode.

You could therefore create a complicated set of nested `#elif` blocks to recognize various compilers' version macros, but it could never be complete or forward-compatible.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. Or rather, it does it an incredibly roundabout way, which just says "no".

Comment: @NeilButterworth It says what is available. Do you think an explicit "no" would add value to it?